# How to make Activity, not covering full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want my activity to take smaller area of the screen e.g. toast doesn't cover all of the screen, it is just shown over other things and rest of the contents can be seen behind the toast. But it's a dialog, and I want my screen to be shown above other things e.g. above Home Screen. Below is the idea that is in my mind.

[image: Activity Taking Smaller Area of the Screen]

Kindly, guide me if it is even possible. If possible then show me the right path.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make your activity theme as translucent.
add the following line in your manifest against that activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

so that you can see the background things add the view to a LinearLayout with `android:alignParentBottom=true`.

Comment: What if i wanted to add this view to random positon, e.g. 50dip from top and 30dip from left. Is there any xml attribute for that? Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions force a style based on Theme.AppCompat. Use this to create a quick dialog style based activity.

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom dialog box.

[Check this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)  and [also this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

you can design you layout transparent so view main activity also.