# AccuWeather like widget bahavior

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to implement widget behavior similar to weather widget by AccuWeather.com.
After single tap it opens/resizes itself (animated way) to show additional information about weather, but does not fully cover whole screen. It just shadows parts of the screen which are not overlapped by it's window.

Any idea how is this implemented? Is it new activity with some layout features? Dialog window? Or maybe there are some options for widget layout transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very probably an Activity as the possibilities for a widget are very limited. There are various examples of Activies not covering the whole screen -- Dialogs are an example. 
Actually, all you need to do is use is a translucent theme to the Activity in the manifest as described here:

[How to make Activity, not covering full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421036/how-to-make-activity-not-covering-full-screen)